# Toggle flags on/off with a button in highcharts/highstock

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I wondered if anybody would know if it's possible in jQuery to have a button that would show/hide the flags displayed on a highcharts stock chart, such as the one in my jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/hcharge/G7rsh/6/

I'm assuming you'd use something like this

```
$('.on').click(function() {
        $('flags').toggle('1000', function() {
         });
    });
```

I'm just not sure how you would reference the flags in the chart?  I'd also like the button to toggle class when it is clicked.  Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: " Torstein Hønsi " no one can say any thing after him but i have one thing to say

Comment: to use jquery to hide and show series you have to use the SVG ELEMENTS as your selector ,

Comment: Good example, but the graph doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [poc fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G7rsh/8/)

Torstein answered before me but that's not fair, he created the lib :-D

BTW, his solution is better than mine

Answer (score 4):

You can call the Series.show() and Series.hide() methods in Highcharts: http://jsfiddle.net/G7rsh/7/

Comment: what's wrong with highcharts jsFIDDLE ... are we see it working soon

Comment: thanks so much for your answer Torstein, and the speed of response! I've gone with Grooveeks answer just because it allowed me to remove multiple flags

Comment: is there a simple way to modify that to work with multiple flags?